# How to filter an array due to length of array it contains and property name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an example array like below

```js
exArray: [
  { prop1: [3, 2], prop2: "a", prop3: 3 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "b", prop3: 7 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "x", prop3: 9 },
];
```

From this array I only need prop1(if length is bigger than 0).So I tried like this below

```js
exArray.map((e) => e.prop1);
```

this one worked but also made other empty prop1s included.

```js
exArray.filter((e) => e.prop1.length > 0 && e.prop1);
```

I expected this would work but didn't

Here what I expect to see below(prop1 and length is bigger than 0)

```js
exArray: [{ prop1: [3, 2] }];
```

I also know that I can combine map and filter but dont want to iterate twice such as:

```js
map((e) => e.prop1).filter((e) => e.prop1.length > 0);
```

How can I iterate once and achieve my expected result?

Comment: If you want to minimize the amount of iterations that you need to do you should `filter` first, then `map` over the result to get the desired output. Also, this seems like a simple case, so `filter` and `map` are probably a better choice here than the `reduce` option below from readability standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce`

```js
const data = [
  { prop1: [3, 2], prop2: "a", prop3: 3 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "b", prop3: 7 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "x", prop3: 9 },
  { prop1: [9], prop2: "y", prop3: 10 },
]

const res = data.reduce(
  (acc, element) =>
    element.prop1 && element.prop1.length > 0
      ? [...acc, { prop1: element.prop1 }]
      : acc,
  []
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `forEach`

```js
let exArray = [ { prop1: [3, 2], prop2: "a", prop3: 3 }, { prop1: [], prop2: "b", prop3: 7 }, { prop1: [], prop2: "x", prop3: 9 }, ];

let res = [];
exArray.forEach((e) => {
  if (e.prop1.length > 0) res.push({ prop1: e.prop1 });
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: He doesn't want the `filter+map` option.

Comment: Yeah didn't notice that, I have changed it to a `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

With modern for loop && destructuring.

```js
exArray = [
  { prop1: [3, 2], prop2: "a", prop3: 3 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "b", prop3: 7 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "x", prop3: 9 },
];

const newArr = [];
for (const {prop1} of exArray) prop1.length > 0 && newArr.push({prop1});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and destructuring

```js
exArray = [
  { prop1: [3, 2], prop2: "a", prop3: 3 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "b", prop3: 7 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "x", prop3: 9 },
];

const res = exArray.reduce(
  (acc, { prop1 }) => (prop1.length ? (acc.push(prop1), acc) : acc),
  []
);

console.log(res)
```

If you need it with `prop1` in object

```js
exArray = [
  { prop1: [3, 2], prop2: "a", prop3: 3 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "b", prop3: 7 },
  { prop1: [], prop2: "x", prop3: 9 },
];

const res = exArray.reduce(
  (acc, { prop1 }) => (prop1.length ? (acc.push({prop1}), acc) : acc),
  []
);

console.log(res);
```